# What is the minimum balance required to create a trustline between accounts?

Tags: assets, trustline

I just attempted to create a trustline between 2 accounts, both with 1 XLM balance, but the transaction failed due to insufficient balance.  I hadn't seen anything that there needed to be an additional balance above the minimum account balance - what is the minimum balance required? FYI I left the trust limit blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trustlines are an additional 0.5 XLM, as are DEX offers, data entries and additional signers.

Comment: I'll just drop it here https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance